# Quicksight: Get Year to Date totals in table visual

Tags: visualization, data-analysis, calculated-columns, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I want to get year to date total in quicksight table visual instead of just total. Currently my visualization looks like below:

[image: Current vs expected output]

**Current**:

```
|**Dates**|Jan20|Feb20|Mar20|Apr20|May20|Jun20|Jul20|Aug20|Sep20|Oct20|Nov20|Dec20|Jan21|**Total**|

|**number**|20  | 30  | 40  |50   |  60 |   75|  14 |15   |  25 |   45|  25 |   36| 21| **456**|
```

**Expected**:

```
|**Dates**|Jan20|Feb20|Mar20|Apr20|May20|Jun20|Jul20|Aug20|Sep20|Oct20|Nov20|Dec20|Jan21|**Total YTD21**| **Total**|

|**number**|20  | 30  | 40  |50   |  60 |   75|  14 |15   |  25 |   45|  25 |   36| 21| **21**| **456**|
```

Is there any way to get YTD total like above in quicksight table visual. Please refer to the attached image for more understanding.

Any help would be appreciated.